# Get "group by" data other than the Key element

Tags: linq

I'm trying to get the sum of fees per customer per month from the mysql sakila database.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
select first_name, last_name, MONTHNAME(payment_date) as Month, sum(amount) as FeeSum
from customer c
join payment p on c.customer_id = p.customer_id
where (payment_date between '2005-01-01' AND '2005-06-30')
group by c.customer_id, Month
order by Month desc, FeeSum desc;
```

I did this in linqpad

```
var q11 =   from c in Customer
        from p in Payment
        where c.Customer_id == p.Customer_id && ((DateTime)p.Payment_date) > DateTime.Parse("2005-01-01") && ((DateTime)p.Payment_date) < DateTime.Parse("2005-06-30")
        group new {c, p} by new {((DateTime)p.Payment_date).Month, p.Customer_id} into grp
        select new {
        Month = grp.Key.Month,
        FeeSum = grp.Sum(s => s.p.Amount),
        } into selection
        orderby selection.Month, selection.FeeSum descending
        select selection;
q11.Dump();
```

Which works for the FeeSum and the Month, but I can't figure out how to get the first_name and the lasT_name of the customer

Comment: Which database brand allows selecting columns that aren't part of the `group by` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Since the members of each `grp` all have the same `Customer`, just pick any one:

```
var q11 = from c in Customer
          from p in Payment
          where c.Customer_id == p.Customer_id && ((DateTime)p.Payment_date) > DateTime.Parse("2005-01-01") && ((DateTime)p.Payment_date) < DateTime.Parse("2005-06-30")
          group new { c, p } by new { ((DateTime)p.Payment_date).Month, p.Customer_id } into grp
          select new {
              grp.First().first_name,
              grp.First().last_name,
              Month = grp.Key.Month,
              FeeSum = grp.Sum(s => s.p.Amount),
          } into selection
          orderby selection.Month, selection.FeeSum descending
          select selection;
```

Note: I prefer to use `let` rather than `select` twice, but it is the same thing internally, I believe:

```
var q11 = from c in Customer
          from p in Payment
          where c.Customer_id == p.Customer_id && ((DateTime)p.Payment_date) > DateTime.Parse("2005-01-01") && ((DateTime)p.Payment_date) < DateTime.Parse("2005-06-30")
          group new { c, p } by new { ((DateTime)p.Payment_date).Month, p.Customer_id } into grp
          let FeeSum = grp.Sum(s => s.p.Amount)
          orderby grp.Key.Month, FeeSum descending
          select new {
              grp.First().first_name,
              grp.First().last_name,
              Month = grp.Key.Month,
              FeeSum
          };
```